# How do I lock the camera horizontal rotation if speed is 0 or less?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a cars game and I'm trying to prevent the camera from moving horizontally if the model speed is null, I have tried many things, however I seem unable to do this because either when I get the camera to get locked it remains locked even if the object moves, and if not that it just keeps moving even with the object stopped, so I want to know how can I make that happen.

Code for cam Class

```cs
public class Cam : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float sensitivityHor = 9.0f;
    public float sensitivityVert = 9.0f;
    public float minimumVert = -45.0f;
    public float maximumVert = 45.0f;

    public enum rotationAxes
    {
        //Given aliases to X and Y cordinates
        keyX = 1,
    }
    public rotationAxes axes = rotationAxes.keyX;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Movement mov = GetComponent<Movement>();
        if (mov.speed > mov.speed && mov.speed > 0 && axes == rotationAxes.keyX)
        {
                //Movimiento en el eje X de la camara
                transform.Rotate(0, Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * sensitivityHor, 0);
        }

    }

}
```

code for Movement class

```cs
public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private CharacterController _charController;
    public float speed = 3.0f;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        _charController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

            float deltaZ = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed;
            Vector3 movement = new Vector3(0, 0, deltaZ);
            movement = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(movement, speed);
            movement *= Time.deltaTime;
            movement = transform.TransformDirection(movement);
            _charController.Move(movement);

    }

}
```

Comment: `mov.speed > mov.speed` is always false.

Comment: I know that, however without that one it won't work either, I've tried many ways to do it but I just seem unable to make it work

Comment: have you stepped through the code in a debugger?

Comment: Not an appropriate question for the [tag:visual-studio] tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never change the value of `speed` so what sense does it make to check it?

Rather store the actual speed you are going to apply to the object in this frame

```
public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("References")]
    [SerializeField] private CharacterController _charController;

    [Header("Settings")]
    [SerializeField] private float speed = 3.0f;

    [Header("Debug")]
    [SerializeField] private float actualSpeed;

    // public Read-only property
    public float ActualSpeed => actualSpeed;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void Awake()
    {
        if(!_charController) _charController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update()
    {
        actualSpeed = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed;
        // It is cheaper to clamp a single float value then a vector
        // since "GetAxis" retusn a value between -1 and 1
        // it will anyway never be greater then "speed" so enough
        // to clamp it downwards
        actualSpeed = Mathf.Max(deltaZ, 0);
        actualSpeed *= Time.deltaTime;

        // This already uses the world space forward vector
        _charController.Move(transfor.forward * actualSpeed);
    }
}
```

And now you can rather check for this `actualSpeed` value

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Movement))]
public class Cam : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("References")]
    // Better reference this already via the Inspector
    [SerializeField] private Movement mov;

    [Header("Settings")]
    [SerializeField] private float sensitivityHor = 9.0f;
    [SerializeField] private float sensitivityVert = 9.0f;
    [SerializeField] private float minimumVert = -45.0f;
    [SerializeField] private float maximumVert = 45.0f;
    [Space]
    [SerializeField] private rotationAxes axes = rotationAxes.keyX;

    public enum rotationAxes
    {
        //Given aliases to X and Y cordinates
        keyX = 1,
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        // as fallback get it ONCE
        if(!mov) mov = GetComponent<Movement>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private  void Update()
    {
        if (mov.ActualSpeed > 0 && axes == rotationAxes.keyX)
        {
            transform.Rotate(0, Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * sensitivityHor, 0);
        }
    }
}
```